# Open an url failed, error message: The interface is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B5)Interop.SHDocVw

Tags: nunit, watin, webtest

I'm doing web test with WatiN and Nunit, when i try to open an url and log on. the following error interrupt me:

```
ADP.OneHR.ATC.Production_SmokingTests.Production_LoginAndOpenOnePageTests.BeginTest(2):
System.Exception : Failed to write log! The interface is unknown. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x800706B5)Interop.SHDocVw at SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2.get_HWND()
at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEBrowser.get_hWnd()
at WatiN.Core.Browser.get_hWnd()
at WatiN.Core.UtilityClasses.CaptureWebPage.CaptureWebPageToFile(Stream stream,
    ImageCodecs imagetype, Boolean writeUrl, Boolean showGuides, Int32 scalePercentage, Int32 quality)
at WatiN.Core.UtilityClasses.CaptureWebPage.CaptureWebPageToFile(String filename, 
    Boolean writeUrl, Boolean showGuides, Int32 scalePercentage, Int32 quality)
at WatiN.Core.DomContainer.CaptureWebPageToFile(String filename)
at ADP.OneHR.ATF.CommonSettings.TestResultLoggingModule.WriteToLogFile(IE ie, 
    String caseName, Boolean result, String actualResult) in     
D:\ADPTest\ADP.OneHR.Test\ADP.OneHR.Test\CommonSettings\TestResultLoggingModule.cs:line 109
```

Comment: oh, one more point: WriteToLogFile() is one method for writing log file, in which i tried to capture the web page to file.

Comment: I guess that you try to write to log file after the browser closes so the method can't get the handle on the window resulting in that error.

Comment: Thanks, but i debugged find it lost IE handle.

Comment: This question appears related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348730/get-around-running-visual-studio-as-administrator-in-windows-7-to-interact-with